# How to create a Queue which accepts any Datatype?

Tags: java, collections, queue

How to insert both String's and Integers in the same Queue ?

Please look at the below program, I have created two objects (`q`, `q1`). Can we insert strings and integers in one `Queue`?

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution {
   public void myMethod() {
      Queue<Integer> q=new PriorityQueue<>();
      Queue<String> q1=new PriorityQueue<>();
      q.add(3);
      q1.add("Eswar");
      System.out.println(q);
      System.out.println(q1);
   }

   public static void main(String...args) {
      Solution s=new Solution();
      s.myMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is very unclear. What is *second object* ?

Comment: q1 is the another object created to insert String.

Comment: So the question is : how to insert both string type and integer type in the same queue ?

Comment: yes - how to insert both string type and integer type in the same queue ?

Comment: I've edit. when you ask you may think about what you really do, you don't want do do somthing 'at same time', just put them in the same container

Comment: The requirement you have seems strange, could you explain the real purpose ? because the solution using a Queue<Object> is dangerous

Comment: It's just for practice.I wanna know if that work's or not.Because,if we create two objects instead of one,it means we are wasting memory, right?

Comment: There is no way of *wasting* if the 2 objects are useful. You'll always consume more memory with more object but it can be requiered to achieve your problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Using a `Queue<Object>` you'll be able to add any type you want, because`Object` is a supertpe of every one. But you cannot use any implementation, like `PriorityQueue` because it requires a `sort` on the elements, and different types are not comparable together. An `ArrayDeque` would be good for that.

```
Queue<Object> q = new ArrayDeque<>();
q.add(5);
q.add("Foo");
q.add(5d);
```

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/5VZ9ir)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
Queue<Object> q=new PriorityQueue<>();
```

But you have to care about correct types now.

Comment: Moler - When i am trying to run a program with your suggestion,facing Runtime Exception.Can you please help me by giving simple program as an example?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work for queue (on List it works fine) I am not sure why.
Maybe because of that: 
"A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects"

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without generics, but its  not recommended as you can have runtime exceptions:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Hi");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

Comment: @Eswar Please understand that you cannot just ask "please help me" when you problem is unclear, and the real purpose is not given, which does not llow to give a correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

It is not suggested to have two different types in the same `Collection` with `Generics` using `Object` or RawType as it might lead to runtime errors,

**Option 1** - Try to keep the `Integer` also in `String` representation If it fills your purpose,

```
Queue<String> q1=new PriorityQueue<>();
q1.add(String.valueOf(1));
q1.add("Eswar");
System.out.println(q1);
```

**Option 2** - Create your own type which contains both and manage in through `enum` if only you have to use `PriorityQueue`. Please note you have to add your own `Comparator`,

**Enum for DataType**

```
enum DataType{
    INTEGER,
    STRING
}
```

**Your Own DataType class**

```
class MyData implements Comparable<MyData>{

    private Integer intValue;
    private String stringValue;
    private DataType type;

    public MyData(Integer intValue) {
        this.intValue=intValue;
        type=DataType.INTEGER;
    }

    public MyData(String stringValue) {
        this.stringValue=stringValue;
        type=DataType.STRING;
    }

    public Integer getIntValue() {
        return intValue;
    }

    public String getStringValue() {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public DataType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type==DataType.INTEGER?intValue.toString():stringValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyData data) {
        //Add your comparator here based on your criteria
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**And the implementation**

```
Queue<MyData> q1=new PriorityQueue<>();
q1.add(new MyData(1));
q1.add(new MyData("Eswar"));
System.out.println(q1);
```

Comment: @azro - Let everyone try to give their best answers.May be everything will help me in the future.Nothing happens in trying,right?

Comment: @azro - Yeah, I understand that friend. Shall I put it in this way - "It is not suggested to have two different types in the same Collection with Generics using Object" - Though it fills the purpose, this might provide runtime errors.

Comment: @Eswar sure, but the sentence he gives is not true, I'm just telling him to be careful when give answer